# Which is the best way to validate current password?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I created a form where the user can update his data account. In this form the user is also able to change the account password, before doing so, I ask him the current password, this is the field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Current Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="oldPassword"
            asp-for="@Model.ExistingPassword" type="password" />
    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
</div>
```

as you can see the `oldPassword` input bound the property `ExistingPassword` which is part of the `ViewModel` of that `View` and have the following declaration:

```
[Required, MinLength(6), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string ExistingPassword { get; set; }
```

when the form is submitted I call the following `ajax` function:

```
$.post(url, user, function (response) {

    //Some stuff

}).done(function (response) {
        alert("Updated executed");
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error happened!");
});
```

the parameter of the function are taken by the form, in particular:

- url: `$(this).attr('action');`
- user: `$(this).serialize();`

the action of the form will call the following controller: `User\UpdateUser`.
Inside the `UpdateUser` method I execute the following check:

```
public async Task<UserProfileViewModel> UpdateUserAsync(UserProfileViewModel updatedUser)
{
    if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(originalUser, updatedUser.ExistingPassword))
       throw new Exception("Invalid password");
```

essentially, the condition check if the current password is correct, if not, then an exception will raised.

Now, my question with this is: how can I know which type of exception the method has generated?

I need to know which type of exception the method `UpdateUser` has generated because there are different exceptions in the method.

Suppose the `Invalid Password` exceptions is raised, I need to display a message inside `invalid-feedback` div, next to `oldPassword`, so the user know why the update has failed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Return JSON e.g. `{ "error": "invalid_old_password" }`. It's probably the easiest way. Don't throw an exception.

Comment: So you throw multiple Exceptions in `UpdateUserAsync()` action method?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I recommend not using an exception except in actual exception circumstances, but given the way you've designed this, you have a few options.

I'd suggest creating a custom "UpdateUserException"  that you can throw that will include additional information, which can be provided by an enum or just string.

```
public class UpdateUserException : Exception {
    public UpdateUserError ErrorCondition;

    public UpdateUserException(UpdateUserError error, string message)
    {
        ErrorCondition = error;
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

then you would throw it

```
throw new UpdateUserException(UpdateUserError.BadPassword, "Invalid Password");
```

then you would catch it

```
try {}
catch (UpdateUserException e)
{
    if (e.ErrorCondition == UpdateUserException.BadPassword)
    {
        // handle your exception.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm interesting in what you said "recommend not using an exception" could you show an implementation with your logic? I'll be grateful, thanks

Comment: @Rockj - There are any number of ways to do it without throwing an exception.  You could wrap things in a "UpdateUserResult" object that returns the UserProfileViewModel as well as any status data you want to return for instance.  maerlin's answer below uses a form of that.

Comment: I doesn't have `BadRequest` class, maybe this is only available in `MVC`

Comment: @Rockj - I think he used it as an example.  You can create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [UserManager ChangePassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.changepasswordasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_ChangePasswordAsync__0_System_String_System_String_) Method.

You can bind the UserManager to use DependencyInjection like this (in Startup.cs)

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
      {
           ...

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();

            var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                UserManager<User> userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
            }

        }
```

And then in your Controller s Constructor

```
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

And finally your endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost("ChangePassword")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword([FromBody]ChangePasswordRequest changePasswordParams)
    {
        if (changePasswordParams == null)
            return BadRequest($"{nameof(changePasswordParams)} must not be null!");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(changePasswordParams.OldPassword) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(changePasswordParams.NewPassword))
            return BadRequest("old and new passwords have to be provided, but they both are empty.");

        var userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id")?.Value;
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, changePasswordParams.OldPassword, changePasswordParams.NewPassword);

        if (result.Succeeded)
            return NoContent();

        return BadRequest(result.Errors);
    }
```

after that you can handle [the errors](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Core/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs) in a switch statement.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'm looking for a more generic solution rather than a specific implementation for `ChangePassword`

Answer (score 0):

Using Exceptions for handled errors are not recommended since they generally ends up with Internal Server error and actually It is beyond of its purpose.

The best approach would be to send BadRequest as It is stated by @maerlin.

However, If you insist to use Exceptions in your application or your applciation is architected to work in this way. I suggest you to inherit new CustomApplcationException class from ApplicationException and then inherit UpdateUserException and vs. from CustomApplicationException class. After that, I Suggest you to handle your exceptions in ErrorHandlingMiddleware and return HandledExceptions at least with BadRequest (400) status code.

The Example Code would be

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILoggerManager _logger;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerManager logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (CustomApplicationException cae)
        { 
            await HandleCustomExceptionAsync(httpContext, cae);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Something went wrong: {ex}");
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails()
        {
            StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
            Message = "Internal Server Error from the custom middleware."
        }.ToString());
    }

    private static Task HandleCustomExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails()
        {
            StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
            Message = exception.Message
        }.ToString());
    }
}
```

then you need to regiter middleware in your Startup.cs

```
 app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
```

please see https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/ and http://www.talkingdotnet.com/global-exception-handling-in-aspnet-core-webapi/ for further details.